# Change the order of CSS files. Load module's CSS before theme's CSS

Tags: layout, magento-1, theme, frontend, configuration

How can I change the order of CSS files to load module's CSS **before theme's CSS**? Here are some code examples:

**Theme's CSS file** (loaded on all pages) added in theme's *local.xml*:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/theme.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**Extension's CSS file** (loaded only on category pages) added in module's XML layout file:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/extension.css</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

This is the order of loaded CSS files which I get on the category page, extension's CSS is loaded after theme's CSS:

> - /default/mytheme/css/styles.css
> - /default/mytheme/css/theme.css
> - /default/mytheme/css/**extension.css**

What I'm trying to achieve: extension's CSS is loaded before theme's CSS.
**How can I force this order of CSS files:**

> - /default/mytheme/css/styles.css
> - /default/mytheme/css/**extension.css**
> - /default/mytheme/css/theme.css

I've noticed that if I have many extensions installed, CSS of some extensions loads before theme's CSS and CSS of some other extensions loads after theme's CSS. I assume that it has something to do with the order of modules in Magento, but I don't understand how I can affect the order of CSS (or JavaScript) files on the frontend.

### EDIT:

About [philwinkle's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3529/764):

but in this case I can't do something like this because it would add layout of the category page to all pages (that CSS file is needed only on category page):

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <update handle="catalog_category_layered" />
    </default>
    
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/extension.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Can this solution be adjusted to my case somehow?

Comment: Very good question, I appreciate an answer :)

Answer (score 6):

@benmarks has a great approach from this SO thread - though his example is for Javascript it can be adapted for CSS, too:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610949/magento-module-layout-xml-load-order

> Another option to try would be to use an  directive in your
>   custom module layout XML, as the directives in an  are
>   processed before the other directives. This means that jQuery will
>   load before all other files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <update handle="add_css_first" />
    </default>

    <add_css_first>
        <action method="addCss" block="head">
            <link>css/custom-styles.css</link>
        </action>
    </add_css_first>
</layout>
```

There are also community modules which exist to allow you to set an explicit sort-order with a rewrite of page/html_head:

https://github.com/drewhunter/ItemPosition

Which allows you to do this sort of customization:

```
 <reference name="head">
        <action method="setLast">
            <last>css/custom-styles.css</last>
        </action>
 </reference>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can this solution be adjusted to my case somehow? I edited my post to include your answer.

Comment: See my edit which is somewhat tailored to your solution. You should also look into the github link I posted. I have no real-world experience with it, but it looks like it would work for your situation.